# How to get user activity logging by Log4Net in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, log4net

I have a MVC 4 application.I tried get user activity logging.

I looked this sample http://www.oakwoodinsights.com/adding-log4net-mvc-site/

But I failed.Log table is empty in SQL.

Firstly I added log4net.2.0.3 package to my project.

I have this table in SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log4Net] (
[ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
[Thread] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL ,
[Level] [varchar] (10) NOT NULL ,
[Logger] [varchar] (1000) NOT NULL ,
[Message] [varchar] (4000) NOT NULL ,
[Exception] [varchar] (4000) NOT NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I added Log4Net.config to my project.

http://pastebin.com/RYpq3xTg

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
 <log4net>
<appender name="DbAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="0" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="{auto}" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log4Net ([date],[thread],[level],[logger],[message],[exception]) VALUES
    (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%t" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%p" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="1000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%c" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%m" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="DbAppender" />
</root>
```

I created a static class in Controller

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers

{

public static class Log4NetManager
{


    public static void InitializeLog4Net()

    {
        XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Log4Net.config"));

        Hierarchy hier = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;

        if (hier != null)
        {
            AdoNetAppender adoAppender = (from appender in hier.GetAppenders()
                                          where appender.Name.Equals("DbAppender", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                          select appender).FirstOrDefault() as AdoNetAppender;

            if (adoAppender != null && adoAppender.ConnectionString.Contains("{auto}"))
            {
                adoAppender.ConnectionString = ExtractConnectionStringFromEntityConnectionString(
                        GetEntitiyConnectionStringFromWebConfig());

                //refresh settings of appender
                adoAppender.ActivateOptions();

            }
        }

    }


    private static string GetEntitiyConnectionStringFromWebConfig()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MemberEntities"].ConnectionString;

 //MemberEntities is like this in  Web.Config : http://pastebin.com/R9wCwRar


  }


    private static string ExtractConnectionStringFromEntityConnectionString(string entityConnectionString)
    {
        // create a entity connection string from the input
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(entityConnectionString);

        // read the db connectionstring
        return entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;
    }
   }
  }
```

Called Log4NetManager.InitializeLog4Net() in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {

        Log4NetManager.InitializeLog4Net();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }
```

And finally get log in localhost:1235/Sample

```
    public class SampleController : Controller

  {
    //
    // GET: /Sample/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SampleController));

        // get current user
        string user = HttpContext.User.Identity.ToString();

        logger.Debug("Debug messages are not recorded due to log level");
        logger.Info("User : "+" "+user.ToString()+" "+"was here");


        try
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            logger.Error("An Error Happened! ", ex);

        }

        }

       return View();

        }
```

But my Log4Net Table is empty after visit localhost:1235/Sample.

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: i wanted to tremendously thank you for posting this code, this helped me immensely!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry.My mistake is I created Log table in SQL.

Change

```
Log
```

to

```
Log4Net
```

It is working.Good sample for user activity loggin in MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

If log4net table is empty, you can check output window to get errors or warnings.

[image: Check Output Windows for Errors on Log4Net]